# LHS of @ (atop) seems to be applied to the whole list as done with @: (at) NB. +/@(*:@:mdev)

Tags: j

In the explanation:

```
n=.1 2 3 4
(+/@*:) n    NB. 1 4 9 16
(+/@:*:) n   NB. 30
```

In the first one the sum (`+/`) is applied on each single result of the square (`*:`), whereas in the second the sum is applied to the whole result list. So far so good. But the next example does not seem to work that way (probably it does. I just don't get it):

```
mean=.+/%#
mdev=.-mean
(*:@:mdev) n          NB. 2.25 0.25 0.25 2.25

ssq=.+/@(*:@:mdev)
ssq n                 NB. 5
+/@(*:@:mdev)         NB. 5 - why not: 2.25 0.25 0.25 2.25
+/@:(*:@:mdev)        NB. 5
```

In `ssq` the bracket expression is fine. It works as expected: `(*:@:mdev) n` results in a list of squares. Here it doesn't matter which `@` or `@:` is used. I understand the difference. But the `@` outside of the bracket should to my understanding sum (`+/`) each item of the result of `(*:@:mdev)`.

Who can enlighten me where my understanding is wrong? Why is the first `@` in `+/@(*:@:mdev)` applied to the whole result list and not to each item as in `(+/@*:)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that `u @: v y` applies `u` to the entire result of `v y` whereas `u @ v y` applies `u` to the intermediate results of `v` based on the rank of `v`.

Forks such as `mean` and hooks such as `mdev` default to infinite rank if you don't specify otherwise with the Rank conjunction (`"`).

This means that

`+/` in  `+/ @ (*: @: mdev)` and `+/ @: (*: @: mdev)`

will have the same rank as

`*: @: mdev`

which in turn will have the same rank as `mdev` which means that `@` will be working on the entire result i.e. infinite rank.

Now, look at the example `+/ @ *: n` where `*:` has a rank of 0 and it works on atoms (you can find ranks of verbs at the top of the dictionary entries for the primitives such as `*:`)

This means that `@` stipulates that `+/` is applied to each atom of n resulting in your list `1 4 9 16`.

For `+/ @: *:` the rank of `*:` has no effect on `+/` because of `@:` and `+/`  is applied to the entire result which is the sum of the list.

For a more in depth reference, chapter 12 of Henry Rich's J for C programmers covers this topic very well.  http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/compound_verbs.htm#_Toc191734368